# How to create an api which when authenticated with LinkedIn returns the list of all the connections of the Person.

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api

I am trying to develop an app which takes LinkedIn as authentication and when successful returns the connection of the authenticated person.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I tried looking at the documentation but could not find an API that still works for connection. I read somewhere the connection API is deprecated, all I have is an api that gives me the basic info of autenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn has now restricted its API, making of lot of endpoint unavailable unless you're a Partner. API to get connections is part of the APIs that are now unavailable.

From their website ([Developer Program Transition](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition)):

> If your application is currently using any other API services (e.g. Connections, Groups, People Search, Invitation, Job Search, etc.) you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program that provides the necessary API access to continue to leverage any of the endpoints that are not listed above.

Comment: But since I have the authentication of the user whose connection I want isn't it basically me wanting to look at my own connection. Is that not possible too?

Comment: The article is quite clear, unless you are a Partner, you can only see a Profile, a people's Share and a Company by its id. Everything else is unavailable.